# Firebase database security rule, check auth.email in resource.data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

> Error [firebase.firestore] FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I have an object that a few users are allowed to update. An admin will set their email, and these users who sign in with those email will be allowed to update.

These are the rules that I have tried:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.managerEmails.val().contains(request.auth.email) && request.resource.data.id == resource.data.id;

allow update: if request.resource.data.managerEmails.contains(request.auth.email) && request.resource.data.id == resource.data.id;

allow update: if request.resource.data.managerEmails.includes(request.auth.email) && request.resource.data.id == resource.data.id;
```

The resource to update:

```
{
  id: "someid",
  ...fields,
  managerEmails: "abcde@email.com,anothermanager@email.com",
}
```

User auth who is updating:

```
{
  uid: "rSTLnYD9aisyZJHQPC6sg7mlsZh1",
  email: "abcde@email.com",
  ...
}
```

Update:
Using `request.auth.uid` has been working in other rules, but in this case, I have to use emails because the users might not have signed up yet.

Using Rules Playground, I get `Property email is undefined on object.` Maybe using `request.auth.email` is not possible?

Answer (score 8):

use: **request.auth.token.email** insted request.auth.email

[documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#define_custom_user_information)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem but switched from using firebase.auth.email to firebase.auth.token.email and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest doing two things.

Firstly, store UIDs instead of email addresses.  A UID is the preferred way to identify a single Firebase Auth account and is always guaranteed to exist and be unique.  Email addresses are not.

Secondly, store the list of users as an array type field instead of comma separated string.  This will be much easier to manage overall.

After you do these two things, the rule becomes simple:

```
allow update: if resource.data.managerUids.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I needed to use email because these users might not have signed up in the system (their user does not exist yet). I have changed it to an array of emails as you have suggested, instead of comma-separated. And changed it to resource.data.managerEmails.hasAny([request.auth.email]), doesn't work too.

Comment: Using Rules Playground, I get `Property email is undefined on object.` Maybe using email is not possible?

Comment: The simulator in the console doesn't support it. You will have to write code to see if it works.